# visual studio 2019 schema compare no differences detected

Tags: sql, .net, compare, schema, visual-studio-2019

I am using New Schema Comparison to compare 2 Databases
but this tools return " compare no differences detected "
I am using VS 2019

Comment: Let's start with the obvious: are you comparing databases with identical schemas? Remember, we only have the information you give us. Please read [ask].

Comment: Seems like a valid question. I have the same problem.

Comment: Check the error list from View -> Error List, mine was timeout issue, I tried by re-selecting source and target and making sure to select "Remember Password", this worked for me.

Comment: Same error, need to check the Error tab, else won't know what happen. VS should have made the error more obvious. Set "Remember Password" fix the issue.

Comment: Try closing visual studio and restarting your PC it works then.

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at the Error List in Visual Studio.

[image: screenshot]

In my case it contained errors, but it's not obvious that an error has occurred from the SQL Schema Compare UI.

Answer (score 1):

I just faced the same problem. In my case, it was because the database user did not have enough privileges.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. As per suggestion of Manthan Devani, I enabled the error list from View -> Error List.
This showed that the user did not have enough priviliges.
The following grant statement solved the issue and I was able to see the comparison result:

```
USE yourDbName
GO
GRANT VIEW Definition TO yourUser
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue, but I was able to resolve it by checking and adjusting the Target Platform in the properties of the DB project.

[image]